# Count in dplyr gives different results

Tags: r, dplyr

I am strugling with a strange behaviour of count in dplyr
Given a df.

```
df =
    tibble(
      x1 = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
      x2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
      )
```

Why this

```
df %>% group_by(x1, x2) %>% count %>% .$n %>% sum
```

Gives a different result from this?

```
df %>% group_by(x1, x2) %>% count %>% sum(.$n)
```

The first one gives the correct result (6). But the second one gives 26?!

Any hint why?

Answer (score 2):

For the second result, the pipe `%>%` inserts the transformed `df` into the first argument, thus summing all three columns (`x1`, `x2`, and `n`) and the added column (`.$n`). What you're doing amounts to:

```
temp <- df %>% group_by(x1, x2) %>% count
sum(temp, temp$n)
[1] 26
```

If you want to avoid the insertion, you can encompass the final call in curly braces:

```
df %>% group_by(x1, x2) %>% count %>% {sum(.$n)}
[1] 6
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot !